# Make ActionBar title uppercase

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

How do I make the ActionBar title uppercase? Some answers suggest putting `<item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>` but this has no effect when I put it in the actionBar style or actionBar's `titleTextStyle`. It only has an effect when I put in in the AppTheme style but that makes a bunch of things in my app also in all caps which I don't want.

My styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- snip snip -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/NewActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="NewActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/text_pink</item> <!-- no effect -->
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/NewActionBarTitle</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|showTitle</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item> <!-- no effect -->
</style>

<style name="NewActionBarTitle">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/tiny_text_size</item> <!-- no effect -->
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item> <!-- no effect -->
</style>
```

And why do the `NewActionBar` and `NewActionBarTitle` styles appear to have no effect no matter what I put in them? Is there something wrong with my styles or my action bar or what?

Edit: I've just deleted entirely the styles `NewActionBar` and `NewActionBarTitle` (and the reference to them in the `AppTheme` style) and the action bar looks completely the same. So something is broken. What could it be?

Comment: Sorry to ask probably this stupid question but why you don't set it uppercase since the first moment?

Comment: Because then the launcher icon will also have the uppercase text (and this clashes with other app icons), and so far there is no consistent solution (that works on all devices) that allows the main activity to have a different title from the launcher icon title.

Comment: why not use toolbar... you will have more freedom on the actionbar...

Comment: Because I don't want to spend a few hours learning about the toolbar and integrating it in my app when its only purpose is to show the activity title and return the user to the main activity. And I doubt I'll ever make another Android app, so learning about the toolbar wouldn't be a good investment of my time just so I could solve the uppercase title problem.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set `android:textAllCaps="true"` on the text appearance for the action bar's title, rather than the action bar style itself or on your base activity theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    ...
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar.Solid</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyApp.ActionBar.Solid"
       parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.MyApp.Widget.ActionBar.Title</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.MyApp.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
       parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: No effect. Nothing I put in those two styles has any effect, the actionbar looks the same. I'm wondering if something is broken. I've even copied your code exactly and it looks the same as it had. Note the `<!-- no effect -->` comments in the code in my question.

Comment: What activity are you extending from? It's possible that it's using the `toolbarStyle` instead of `actionBarStyle`, in which case I can update the solution with the appropriate styles.