# Xamarin Android - ContentPage.Title always Uppercase

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

How can I stop the title of a ContentPage always being uppercase on Android?

I managed to sort out buttons with a custom renderer and `SetAllCaps(false)` but I can't find anything about how to do that with a content pages' Title.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is probably a setting in your theme

Comment: you can refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333139/make-actionbar-title-uppercase